# NoSQL as local storage for logging and tracing

Tags: nosql

We are developing application which will have many physical servers. We want to use NoSQL for logging and tracing since it does not required structured data.

We don't want to have Centralized logging.

Can we install NoSQL (any one) in each server and store logging/tracing details? Will NoSQL impact my actually process in the server? Is it good idea to do it?

Comment: I don't know of a product named "NoSQL". Did you have a particular product or tool in mind, or only a concept?

Comment: NoSQL is not a product. It's a concept. There are many NoSQL database out in market. Visti http://nosql-database.org/ for more info.

Answer (score 5):

#### Problem1: Data Collection

Many people're using NoSQL solutions for storing application logs. The first challenge you may have is how to collect huge amount of data from various data sources reliably with ease of management. One concern of not having log collection layer, is lock contention of database caused by high write throughput.

So basically having log collection layer is recommended. There're some open-source log collector implementation such as syslog, [Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/), [Scribe](http://github.com/facebook/scribe), and [Flume](http://github.com/cloudera/flume/) :)

#### Problem2: Storage & Processing

The next big problem is how to store and process data. The backend infrastructure requires a lot of changes as the data volume increase. At first, you can use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) to store all of your data, but at some moment you end up using [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) to architect a massively scalable architecture.

Here's an example architecture of having Fluentd for log collection, and MongoDB for log storage and processing.

[image: fluentd plus mongodb]

Here're some links to put the Apache Logs into Amazon S3, MongoDB, or Hadoop HDFS by Fluentd.

- [Store Apache Logs into Amazon S3](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/apache-to-s3)
- [Store Apache Logs into MongoDB](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/apache-to-mongodb)
- [Fluentd + HDFS: Instant Big Data Collection](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/http-to-hdfs)

Disclaimer: I'm a committer of Fluentd project.

Answer (score 0):

definitely this is good idea for doing same thing with nosql rather than sql.
because in logging and tracing **volume of data is high** and **ratio of retrieving data** is also high.

you for logging and tracing you **need complex reports for analysis** so nosql is better for you.

also **nosql support distributed environment** so you create infrastructure at different geographic location.